# Photoshop PDF Edit XML Then "Refresh" and Save New PDF

Tags: php, pdf, photoshop

When you save a Photoshop doc as a PDF it generates some XML elements which I assume are used by Photoshop for editing later. Anyway, a portion of these nodes look like this:

```
<rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
    <photoshop:LayerName>Item 1</photoshop:LayerName>
    <photoshop:LayerText>Item 1</photoshop:LayerText>
</rdf:li>
<rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
    <photoshop:LayerName>Item 2</photoshop:LayerName>
    <photoshop:LayerText>Item 2</photoshop:LayerText>
</rdf:li>
```

Obviously it's easy to replace some of the text in the nodes, but what I'm wondering is if there is someway (a tool, library, anything) that would "refresh" or re-compile the PDF using the new data in the nodes on the server; preferably in PHP.

I need to replace some placeholder text dynamically. That's the goal.

If I'm on the wrong track, is there any way for this to be accomplished?
I'm willing to try to edit any file (good enough for print) like this whether it's a psd, pdf, indesign, ai, anything.

Thanks!

Comment: there are tools to generate pdf files with php, if that's what you want - i'm not sure where photoshop fits

Comment: I know there are tools to generate pdfs. I've used a couple of them before. What I want is something that takes a pdf (already) created by a designer, who used placeholders (something that works like twig or mustache templating for php), and be able to change those placeholders dynamically with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're posting as example is probably not XML as such but part of the XMP information in the file. XMP is a metadata format designed to be put inside of many file formats (PDF, image file formats, you name it).

The cool thing about XMP is that it was designed to be able to read it and even write it from and to file formats without actually understanding the file format. Meaning that you can scan a document and find all XMP packets without actually having to use a PDF library to parse the complete PDF file for example.

All information about XMP is here on the Adobe web site. They have an SDK for it too and if I remember correctly they even have a free library to read and write XMP for a number of languages (but it's been a while since I've used that).
http://www.adobe.com/products/xmp/

Comment: I should have said xml-like markup; thanks for the correct name! I've looked over the docs for the xmp sdk and I see how I can manipulate that data, but I don't see how I can use that data to "refresh" or rebuild the pdf after manipulating the data. That's the part I'm really struggling with. I basically want to change dummy text with text entered by a user dynamically.

Comment: You're still correct because XMP actually is an XML dialect (with some discovery and so so on features thrown in). Do you want to change the data in the XMP itself only or do you then also want the PDF to reflect the changes you've done to the XMP? The former is simple as you can write to the XMP packet (if it has additional padding at the end so you don't disturb the PDF file around it). The latter is not how XMP works. The data in the XMP is completely separate from the PDF code around it - if you want the PDF code to change, you'll be responsible for changing it...

Comment: I thought that I may have been going in the wrong direction with the XMP. I just need to change the text in the PDF. I was hoping I could get to it through the XMP; but as I was searching I found no way to do that. It looks like I'm going to have to overlay text on an image and embed that into a PDF. I didn't want to do that because I wanted more flexibility as to where the text was going and was hoping there was a way to modify the text through a PDF, PSD, AI, or any other format.

Comment: I think your understanding is correct - that is what I was referring to in my last comment. Changing the XMP is easy enough, but there is no "free" synchronization with the PDF content nor any way to magically update the PDF content by editing the XMP. If you want to add content to the PDF itself, you'll need to update the PDF...